# incrementally updating SQL rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm currently dealing with two tables.

One table contains a set of columns like ID, NAME, AGE, TEAM, SCHOOL, and so forth in a table called PRIMARY_TABLE

And I also have an audit table called SECONDARY_TABLE that records updates in the aforementioned values over time.

I have ATTRIBUTE, PREV_VALUES and RECORD_ID columns in this table.  It has the following attributes:

- the RECORD_ID column corresponds to the ID column of PRIMARY_TABLE
- the ATTRIBUTE column will store the column of the PRIMARY_TABLE that is being altered.

For example, if I have

```
132 NIKO 18 LANCERS JESUIT
143 KEENAN 25 RAIDERS ROCKLAND
```

in my first table and

```
132 'AGE' 22
132 'NAME' STEVAN
```

in my second,

then I want a combined table that has

```
132 NIKO 18 LANCERS JESUIT
132 NIKO 22 LANCERS JESUIT
132 STEVAN 22 LANCERS JESUIT
143 KEENAN 25 RAIDERS ROCKLAND .
```

The issue I have a hard time getting around is preserving the values in the unaffected rows.  It seems like any idea I have for joining the two tables together won't work for this reason.

Any thoughts?  I think the only solution is to create a stored procedure for this.  If you need clarification, let me know as well.

**EDIT**

One more thing...

Here's another thing.  The audit table also has a "time_of_change" column.  If multiple rows have the same time of change for an ID, then instead of having multiple rows in our resulting table, there should be only one more row.

For example, if our audit table had

```
132 'AGE' 22 1:00
132 'NAME' STEVAN 1:00
```

Then instead of having

```
132 STEVAN 18 LANCERS JESUIT
132 NIKO   22 LANCERS JESUIT
```

added, there should only be one added row of
`132 STEVAN 22 LANCERS JESUIT`.

I can't think of any possible way to do this either.

Comment: The Input and Output doesn't make any **`Sense`**

Comment: Without having a datetime, or auotincrementing id field of it's own in the secondary table, you have no way of tracking the order in which fields were modified.  Usually when building an audit table, the audit table I build will have it's own id field, a changetype field (I/U/D), a change time field (datetime), and then one field for every field in the auditted table.  It makes looking through logs much easier.

Comment: Does the audit table also have the current value or only the old values? If it only stores the old values, you've made things harder for yourself... :)

Comment: Yes indeed, there is a really awesome way to do this (not 100% automatically but would very much assist with creating an SP that could create views for each table for you) that is much more complicated if you don't have the current values in the audit table...

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE2** If you were to have a column with a datetime of an update in the secondary_table (lets call it `updated_at`) then you can order the resultset appropriately.

```
SELECT id, name, age, team, school, GETDATE() updated_at 
  FROM primary_table
UNION ALL
SELECT p.id, 
       CASE WHEN s.attribute = 'NAME'   
            THEN s.prev_values ELSE p.name END name,
       CASE WHEN s.attribute = 'AGE'    
            THEN s.prev_values ELSE p.age END age, 
       CASE WHEN s.attribute = 'TEAM'   
            THEN s.prev_values ELSE p.team END team, 
       CASE WHEN s.attribute = 'SCHOOL' 
            THEN s.prev_values ELSE p.school END school,
       updated_at
  FROM primary_table p JOIN secondary_table s
    ON p.ID = s.record_id
ORDER BY id, updated_at DESC
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/57d23/1)** demo

**UPDATE1** A version with one `UNION` and conditional output with `CASE`

```
SELECT * 
  FROM primary_table
UNION ALL
SELECT p.id, 
       CASE WHEN s.attribute = 'NAME'   
            THEN s.prev_values ELSE p.name END name,
       CASE WHEN s.attribute = 'AGE'    
            THEN s.prev_values ELSE p.age END age, 
       CASE WHEN s.attribute = 'TEAM'   
            THEN s.prev_values ELSE p.team END team, 
       CASE WHEN s.attribute = 'SCHOOL' 
            THEN s.prev_values ELSE p.school END school
  FROM primary_table p JOIN secondary_table s
    ON p.ID = s.record_id
ORDER BY id
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/853ef/8)** demo

**Original** version with `UNION`s

```
SELECT * 
  FROM primary_table
UNION ALL
SELECT p.id, s.prev_values, p.age, p.team, p.school
  FROM primary_table p JOIN secondary_table s
    ON p.ID = s.record_id
   AND s.attribute = 'NAME'
UNION ALL
SELECT p.id, p.name, s.prev_values, p.team, p.school
  FROM primary_table p JOIN secondary_table s
    ON p.ID = s.record_id
   AND s.attribute = 'AGE'
ORDER BY id
```

Output:

```
|  ID |   NAME | AGE |    TEAM |   SCHOOL |
-------------------------------------------
| 132 |   NIKO |  18 | LANCERS |   JESUIT |
| 132 | STEVAN |  18 | LANCERS |   JESUIT |
| 132 |   NIKO |  22 | LANCERS |   JESUIT |
| 143 | KEENAN |  25 | RAIDERS | ROCKLAND |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c394f/12)** demo

Comment: What if I want to take care of any arbitrary column?  I want to generalize this beyond just the AGE and NAME columns.  Do I just have to do a massive UNION ALL for that?

Comment: @Glassjawed Yes, you do. Because you store your data in a weird way, you have to query it with weird queries. That's only fair.

Comment: @Glassjawed See updated answer for a version with only one `union all`

Comment: @peterm Of course, you still have to name all attributes (NAME, AGE, etc), since the second table reflects on the heading of the first table. And such reflection almost always means that there is a better, more elegant and more efficient (in time at least) DB design.

Comment: @peterm, thanks!

But if the name and age change had the same update time listed in the audit table, I don't want the end result to be in the form

`132 STEVAN 18 LANCERS JESUIT `
`132 NIKO   22 LANCERS JESUIT `

but as

`132 STEVAN 22 LANCERS JESUIT`

Answer (score 0):

This is not perfect but try this one:

```
SELECT * FROM Primary_Table
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT A.ID, A.Name, B.GetAge as Age, A.School
 FROM Primary_Table A INNER JOIN (SELECT Record_id, CONVERT(int,Value) as GetAge FROM    Secondary_Table
 WHERE Attrib='AGE'  ) B
 ON A.ID = B.Record_id) UAge
 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT A.ID, B.GetName as Name, A.Age, A.School
FROM Primary_Table A INNER JOIN (SELECT Record_id, Value as GetName FROM    Secondary_Table
WHERE Attrib='NAME'  ) B
ON A.ID = B.Record_id) UName
ORDER BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some script to get you started. You have a big job ahead of you. Things are made quite a bit more difficult if you don't have the current values in the audit table (which it seems like, so I built my script with that assumption).

```
WITH Curr AS (
   SELECT
      Record_ID = T.ID,
      V.*,
      Time_Of_Change = Convert(datetime, 0)
   FROM
      dbo.Team T
      CROSS APPLY (VALUES
         ('Name', Convert(varchar(20), T.Name)),
         ('Age', Convert(varchar(20), T.Age)),
         ('Team', Convert(varchar(20), T.Team)),
         ('School', Convert(varchar(20), T.School))
      ) V (Attribute, Prev_Values)
),
Data AS (
   SELECT
      H.Record_ID,
      H.Time_Of_Change,
      C.Attribute,
      A.Prev_Values
   FROM
      (
         SELECT DISTINCT Record_ID, Time_Of_Change
         FROM dbo.Audit
         WHERE TableName = 'Team'
         UNION ALL
         SELECT DISTINCT ID, GetDate()
         FROM dbo.Team
      ) H
      CROSS JOIN (VALUES
         ('Name'), ('Age'), ('Team'), ('School')
      ) C (Attribute)
      CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT TOP 1 *
            FROM (
              SELECT Record_ID, Attribute, Prev_Values, Time_Of_Change
              FROM dbo.Audit
              WHERE TableName = 'Team'
              UNION ALL
              SELECT *
              FROM Curr
           ) A
         WHERE
            H.Record_ID = A.Record_ID
            AND H.Time_Of_Change >= A.Time_Of_Change
            AND C.Attribute = A.Attribute
         ORDER BY
            A.Time_Of_Change DESC
      ) A
)
SELECT *
FROM
   Data
   PIVOT (Max(Prev_Values) FOR Attribute IN (Name, Age, Team, School)) P
;
```

### [See a Live Demo at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a1ad9/1)

You can very easily create a view for each table you want to reconstruct the history of. Build a stored procedure that queries the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` view and builds something similar to what I've given you. Run the SP once after any table change, and it will update the views.

I noticed that my script is not quite right--it's showing 2 rows instead of 3 for the edits. Plus, there's no valid time for the rows for which there are no audit rows. But that part makes sense. In any case, you have a big job ahead of you...